# Pointer to pointer as argument in a function

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
void change_adrs(int **q)
{
    int * otheraddess;
    *q = otheraddress; 
}
```

I can't understand this assignment: `*q = otheraddress;`

Could anybody help me to explain this. Why can't we use another assignment, such as:

```
**q = otheraddress; 
*q = *otheraddress;
q = &otheraddress;
```

Answer (score 1):

After declaring the variables, `*` dereferences them.

For example after declaring something like `int **a;`, when using it we have:

`**a` value in value in location stored in `a`(which is ultimately an int)

`*a` value in location stored in `a` (which is another location)

`a`  location stored in `a`

`&a` location of `a` itself

Lets take a look and see why each of your examples don't work:

`**q = otheraddress;` assigning a location to an int ×

`*q = *otheraddress;` assigning an int to a location ×

Edit: Lets take a look at these two examples:

`q = &otheraddress;` assigning a location to a location ✓

`*q = otheraddress;` assigning a location to a location ✓

---

Lets look at it this way:

### Suppose we have:

```c
int *a;
int **q;
```

in order to prevent segmentation faults in the future, lets first assign some address to a:

```c
int t = 5
a = &t;
```

Lets look at the addresses after`q = &a`:

```c
//first snippet
0x7fffc3a2b338   // &a
0x5596853c98c0   // a
5                // *a

0x7fffc3a2b340   // &q
0x7fffc3a2b338   // q
0x5596853c98c0   // *q
5                // **q
```

As expected, `&a` is put into `q`, and `a` holds `&t`, so `**(&a)` and `**(q)` will both hold a value of 5.

Now lets look at the addresses after`*q = a`:

```c
//second snippet
0x7fffc3a2b338   // &a
0x5596853c98c0   // a
5                // *a

0x7fffc3a2b340   // &q
0x7fffc3a2b345   // q
0x5596853c98c0   // *q
5                // **q
```

Here, `a` is put into `*q`, and `a` itself is `&t`, so `*(a)` and `*(*q)` with both hold a value of 5.

To understand the difference, we look at an example:

```c
int b = 3;
a = &b;
```

Using this after the first snippet, `a` is given another address, and `q` was declared `&a`(which hasn't changed), therefore `**(q)` has the same value as `**(&a)`, which is now 3.
This is just like saying:

```c
int a = 3;
int *b = &a;
a = 5; //even though a has changed, b retains its old value of &a, thus *(b) == *(&a) == 5
```

However on the second snippet, `*q` was already declared as `a` before it had changed, so even though `a` now has a new address, the address inside `*q` still hasn't changed. Thus trying to access `*(*q)` will use the old address and give us 5 again.
This is just like saying:

```c
int a = 3; 
int b = a; 
a = 5; //even though a has changed, b still retains it's old value of 3
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but *(&otheraddress) contains an "address" not an "int". Could you review this ?

Comment: @DaiNguyen My apologies for the mistake. I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
void change_ptr(int **q)
{
    *q = malloc(somemem); 
}

void foo()
{
     int *ptr;

     change_ptr(&ptr);
}
```

in this example it will change the value of the `ptr` itself. When you pass a single star pointer you can only change the referenced object.

Comment: That's the key. You may want to expand on the fact that C is pass-by-value and there is no pass-by-reference. So to simulate pass-by-reference where there is the possibility that the address of the pointer itself might change in a function, the *address of* the pointer is passed so the function receives a copy that holds the *address of* the original. Otherwise the change `*q = otheraddress;` would never be seen back in the caller. (as his question is written with `int * otheraddess;`, in the caller, `p` will point to an address that has gone out of scope after the function returns)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the assignment of `*q = otheraddress;` the same as you look at the following:

```
int x = 4;
int y = x;
```

you take 2 vairables of the same type and make an assignment between both of them.

In your case, you use the address of int vairables.
`int *otheraddress;`  is a vairable who can get an address (& operator) to int vairable such as:

```
int x = 4;
int *p = &x; //p<=the address of x
```

and `int **q;` can get an address of a vairable which can get int address. such as you 3rd assignment **(which should work fine)**:

```
int x = 4;
int *p = &x;//p<=the address of x
int **q = &p;//q<=the address of p
```

for the other assignmets:

`**q = otheraddress;` you try to assign int* into int**

`*q = *otheraddress;` you try to assign int into int *